# Finding the mean and median of a probability density function

Tags: statistics, random-variables

I suspect this is super-easy, but I haven't done any math in about ten years and I'm working with concepts that have been woefully explained...

I need to find the mean and median of a continuous random variable that has a probability density function of:

$f(x) = 2x^{-3}$ for $x > 1$

I know that this involves working out integrals and whatnot but, again, this is one of those concepts that wasn't actually explained to me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

let $X$ be some random variable with density $f$.

The mean of $X$ is
$E(X)=\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf(x)dx=\int_{1}^{\infty}2x^{-2}dx=(-\frac2x|_{1}^{\infty}=2$.

And the median of $X$ is $M$ such that
$\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{M}f(x)dx = \frac12$.

$\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{M}f(x)dx = \int_{1}^{M}2x^{-3}dx = (-x^{-2}|_{1}^{M} = 1-\frac1{M^2}$

therefore $\displaystyle\frac1{M^2}=\frac12$ which means $M=\sqrt2$

Comment: I already had those formulae. This doesn't address my main problem of not knowing how to calculate the integral (or even really understanding what the integral means)

Comment: I added the solution of those integrals, but you should learn how to do that in order to manage to solve those kind of problems..

Comment: Basic calculus: $\int ax^b dx= \frac{a}{b+1}x^{b+1}+C$

Answer (score 2):

The median is the point of equal areas on either side. The mean is the point of balance, which is basically the center of mass if the probability density function was solid.

Median = $\int_{-\infty}^M f(x) dx = \frac{1}{2}$ or the area equals 1/2 (since the total area is 1)

Mean = $\frac{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xf(x)dx}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)dx}$ but since $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)dx = 1$ its just $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xf(x)dx$ (formula for center of mass)

Hope this provides some justification for the integral formulas.